# making a content recommendation system

Tags: node.js, express

I am making a blog and want a way to recommend other articles to people based on the current article they are looking at. I am not sure how this is typically done, so this is my attempt.

First, I have this JSON file (articles.json) of every article route and a keyword about that article.

```
[{
        "linkToArticle": "/article1",
        "keywords": ["legos"]
    },
    {
        "linkToArticle": "/article2",
        "keywords": ["houses"]

    },
    {
        "linkToArticle": "/article3",
        "keywords": ["legos"]
    }
]
```

Here is my article1 view and my implementation of recommending other articles:

```
app.get("/article1", (req, res) => {
    let rawData = fs.readFileSync('./articles.json');   // get contents from articles.json
    let data = JSON.parse(rawData);                     // parse content to JSON
    let route = req.originalUrl;                        // get the route "/article1"
    let keywords;
    
        // gets the keyword associated with current article
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
            if (route === data[i]["linkToArticle"]) {
                keywords = data[i]["keywords"];
            }
        }

        // check what other articles have that same keyword
        // and pass to ejs
        let linksToRelatedArticles = [];
        for (let j = 0; j < data.length; ++j) {
            if (keywords.includes(data[j]["keywords"][0])) {
                linksToRelatedArticles.push(data[j]["linkToArticle"]);
            }
        }
        res.render("article1.ejs", { "links": linksToRelatedArticles });
    })
```

My questions are:

1. is this typically how content recommendation is done?
2. Is there a better, more standard way to do this for a small blog?
3. Is this method inefficient? This method requires reading the entire articles.json file for every route.

Answer (score 1):

Content recommendation can be done in a great many ways of dramatically varying complexity. Using keywords is a great simple solution that could easily be reworked later as you get more data on these articles to use for recommendations.

A more efficient way to do this would be to use a database, which will be able to query and retrieve these articles faster.